# Objective c iPhone app and Mac app communication

Tags: objective-c, performance, macos

Is this possible?

I want to be able to press a button on the iPhone app and something happens to the Mac app. Maybe via 3G and wifi.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both Mac OS and iOS support numerous network APIs, including [CFNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html). You could use [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNetService_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to let the iPhone discover the Mac (or vice versa).

Comment: Can you post a quick example?

Comment: There is no quick example without more information.   There are dozens of solutions,  each suited to a particular problem space.  There is also tons of documentation and lots of examples. Do some basic research and then ask a specific question.